# Seek for suggestion of importing data to Django from external database

Tags: python, mysql, django

I am writing a API by Django to do something like every morning retrieve the yesterday trading data from external MYSQL database, do some mapping and finally return the set of formatted data to front-end. Since I am new to handle the data from external data, I have no idea which is the best way to achieve the goal. I am thinking to connect local and the legacy database in django at the same time and then set a crontab to migrate the new data from the legacy database to local database everyday. However, I think it may have high chance getting error during the migration. Are there any other method directly retrieve the data from legacy database and allow me to the mapping immediately?

```
Reference code for connecting 2 database:
Settings.py
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'NAME': 'django_database',
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'USER': '',
        'PASSWORD': ''
    },
    'legacy': {
        'NAME': 'legacy_database',
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'USER': '',
        'PASSWORD': ''
    }
}
Migration.py
from django.db import connections
from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist
from django.db.utils import ConnectionDoesNotExist    
from my_app import models

def setup_cursor():
    try:
        cursor = connections['legacy'].cursor()
    except ConnectionDoesNotExist:
        print "Legacy database is not configured"
        return None
***below have some method save the data into database***
```

Comment: Can you use [replication](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-howto.html)?

Comment: @danblack, thanks for you reply, but I can't.